# Complete operator base logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that $F={0,\to}$ is a complete operator basis by giving equivalent formulas for negation,conjunction and disjunction over F.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts. For example, were you able to handle the case of negation?

Comment: I suppose that $0$ stand for the *false*, more often represented as $\bot$; if so, $\lnot p$ must be define as : $p \to \bot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Polish notation.

Np is equivalent to Cp0.

Kpq is equivalent to NCpNq, which by the above is equivalent to CCpCq00.

Apq is equivalent to CNpq, which by the above is equivalent to CCp0q.

Comment: Could you please put the solution in standard boolean algebra notation? I am a newbie to this field and not able to understand these symbols in polish notation. Thanks!

Comment: @learner Sorry, but no.  I feel like I'm treading a thin line by posting this in the first place, because this seems suspiciously like homework.  I'd suggest this short primer on Polish notation: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html  Take the formation rules in Polish notation and build them up from their variables and connectives.  Translate as you go along and I suspect you will manage to do so for yourself.

Comment: @learner: you can easily transform it. just google it or try prefix to infix conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I figured out.